# How to switch angular app full url?

Tags: angularjs

I have angular app working well under /app#/index and another page on /newapp#/about

So my question is is there anyway, i can switch from url1 to url2?

Because I have different layouts for /app and /newapp

I know that i can use $location.path to change view, but that will change it to
 /app#/index => /app#/about, which I don't want.

Any Ideas?

Comment: On which action you are actually navigating from one page to another, it's a button click or an anchor click?

Comment: Yes, button click will be good.

Comment: Then the first answer is the best way to do this, but you are not going to do this because user may have to sign in again. So tell me one thing, when the user will press "ctrl+r" what will happen then and why are you trying to save something in client side with javascript. It's not the way. If you really want to save something in the client side you have to use cookie

Comment: Now I am not using cookie, all the info of user I am getting is from API call, so if ctrl+r press then user will be logged out. So may be I should use cookie or not, but I am not sure I should do that way or not. I am new to angular.

Comment: If you really want to keep user logged in, you must save that data in somewhere or when user will reload("ctrl+r") the user will be logged out. And the problem for which you have wanted help, I believe the fist answer is the best way to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$location` is only useful for observing the current location, and changing it to paths the app can route to. If you need to navigate the user to a location outside of the app, you'll need to `$window.location.href = '/newapp#/about'`.

If you are providing links via `<a>`, you should be alright. [There are three scenarios (See "Html Link Rewriting")](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) where AngularJS will let the browser navigate to the new URL normally:

1. There is a `target` attribute: `<a href="/app" target="_self">Refresh /app</a>`
2. There is an absolute URI in `href` to another domain: `<a href="http://www.google.com">Redirect to google</a>`
3. The absolute path (one beginning with `/`) has a different base than the current app: `<a href="/newapp">Redirect to /newapp</a>`

Comment: But with <a> page will reload and $scope will be lost, so user again have to sign in. That's what I want to avoid.